# Cannot from gevent.event import Event on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to port a program that is running perfectly fine on my iMac to the raspi 4.
In order to access a data source over a websocket I use the following:

```
from gevent.event import Event
```

And get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/mnt/samsung-ssd/python-projects/dn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/__init__.py", line 86, in <module> from gevent._hub_local import get_hub File "/mnt/samsung-ssd/python-projects/dn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/_hub_local.py", line 101, in <module> import_c_accel(globals(), 'gevent.__hub_local') File "/mnt/samsung-ssd/python-projects/dn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/_util.py", line 105, in import_c_accelmod = importlib.import_module(cname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: /mnt/samsung-ssd/python-projects/dn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/__hub_local.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877612/cannot-from-gevent-event-import-event-on-raspberry-pi-4

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Apparently posted same question twice. Deleted the other one.

Comment: You picked a good one to keep :)